# How to prove $\sin x$ is not a rational function?

Tags: trigonometry, rational-functions

Today I encountered a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439133/what-is-a-rational-trigonometric-function-is-cos-x-rational) about a rational trigonometric function.

My thought: $\sin x$ doesn't give exact values like they are non-ending decimal number that's why it is like this. But in the second answer for that question that person told that rt2sinx is a rational trigonometric function, so how is it possible when rt2 is multiplied to it. In that answer rtsinx is there but I thought it won't make any difference. Please tell me whether I am going wrong somewhere (Like with my thoughts).

Comment: It has infinitely many zeroes.

Comment: But what about 1+sinx and rt2sinx same case with that as well??

Comment: $1+\sin(x)$ takes the value $1$ infinitely often.   For the other, I'm guessing you mean $\sqrt {\sin (x)}$ but, again, that has infinitely many zeroes.

Comment: Rational functions can never be periodic (unless they are constant).  That's an exercise worth proving.

Comment: The term "[rational function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function)" has nothing to do with rational numbers. And the term "rational trigonometric function" as defined in the question you link to, has only little to do with a rational function.

Comment: Oh, I didn't look at your link.  Yes, that linked question appears to have very little to do with rational functions.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I didn't know about it. I changed it.

Comment: @lulu then according to you there should be some mistake in the answers given for that question. Right or wrong?? Because they told 1+sinx and rt2sinx as rational function.

Comment: No, they didn't.  "Rational functions" are, by definition, expressible as the quotient of two polynomials.  The linked question is talking about something else entirely.